# Scroll seems to be not working in tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js, overflow, tailwind-css

Hi I am a beginner to tailwind css and all i want is a problem that has been occuring to me I want to create a scrollable view with the title headings staying in place and the data below the heading in the table to be scrollable but when I use `flex flex-col` [image]

the scroll seems to be working but the data seems to contract but as soon as I remove `flex flex-col`
[image: .]
it comes back to the position but the scroll doesn't work. Can you please say me how do I do it . I want the title to stay in place but the data should be scrollable.Please note that there is a search bar on top of this table.I want the table to be static also and be seen so `top-0` didn't work for me. This is my code .

```js
<div className="mt-5 overflow-x-auto rounded-lg">
          <table className=" h-80 w-full text-left text-sm text-gray-400">
            <thead className="bg-[#292A33] text-xs uppercase">
              <tr className="">
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Name
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Status
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Size
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Type
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Origin
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  nft Image
                </th>
                <th className=" px-6 py-3">
                  Total Price
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody className="overflow-y-scroll">
              {nftinfo.map((nft) => (
                <tr className=" hover:bg-zinc-700 ">
                  <th scope="row" className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-white ">
                    
                  </th>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4">{nft.status}</td>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4">{nft.size}</td>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4">{nft.type}</td>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4">{nft.origin}</td>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4">{nft.image}</td>
                  <td
                    className={`px-6 py-4 ${
                      nft.totalprice > 5000
                        ? ` text-green-500`
                        : `text-red-500`
                    }`}
                  >
                    $ {nft.totalprice}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please provide a code example that shows your problem, for example on https://play.tailwindcss.com

Comment: Hi @ptts I have edited the above message again. Please refer to it again and let me know the answer

Comment: Hi, you still only include screenshots of your code. Can you provide a minimal code example, for example on play.tailwindcss.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below table to I have created, just make sure to replace `class` to `className` and do changes accordingly.

Try to watch the below code with `full page` as it is for `desktop screen` and do changes according to mobile view if you want.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="container m-auto p-4">
  <h1 class="mb-8 text-center text-3xl font-bold">Scrollable Table Fixed Height</h1>

  <table class="w-full border-[1px] border-black text-left">
    <thead class="flex w-full bg-[#292A33] text-xs text-gray-400">
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT NAME</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT STATUS</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT SIZE</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT TYPE</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT ORIGIN</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">NFT IMAGE</th>
        <th class="w-1/4 p-4">TOTAL PRICE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Remove the nasty inline CSS fixed height on production and replace it with a CSS class — this is just for demonstration purposes! -->
    <tbody class="flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-between overflow-y-scroll bg-white text-gray-400" style="height: 60vh;">
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex w-full hover:bg-zinc-700">
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.name</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.status</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.size</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.type</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.origin</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">nft.image</td>
        <td class="w-1/4 p-4">total price</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```